How to plot a graph showing the total number of HTTP requests per hour over the last 2 days in Prometheus?
I have a counter that tracks the number of HTTP requests. I need to plot a graph where each point represents the total number of requests that occurred in the last hour from that point (for example, the point at 2:00 will show how many requests occurred between 1:00 and 2:00).
Is it possible to achieve this with a single query in Prometheus, or do I need to make multiple queries, each referring to the hour I want?
I tried the following approach to collect the total number of HTTP requests per hour over the last 2 days using Prometheus. The code below makes a request to the query_range API with the metric http_requests_total and the time range set to 48 hours ago, with a step of 1 hour (3600 seconds):
const timestamp = new Date();
const startTime = new Date(timestamp);
startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours() - 48);

msg.startTime = startTime.toISOString();
msg.endTime = timestamp.toISOString();

const query = `
  sum (
    increase(http_requests_total[1h])
  ) by (status_code)
`;

msg.url = `http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/query_range` +
  `?query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}` +
  `&start=${encodeURIComponent(new Date(msg.startTime).getTime() / 1000)}` +
  `&end=${encodeURIComponent(new Date(msg.endTime).getTime() / 1000)}` +
  `&step=3600`;

return msg;


"Is it possible ... with a single query" - yes. And your query/request pair should do it, as far as I can tell. Also you can see how same is done in Prometheus' webUI

@markalex, in my case, with Prometheus scrapes configured to fetch counter metrics every 5 seconds, it is not working as I expect. I'm not getting absolute integer values ​​in the results nor are the points plotted at exact times.
I'm not sure it's possible or coherent to model what I want with a counter and the scrapes configuration I'm using.

This is known quirk of Prometheus: increase might produce non integer result even for integer only metric. There is no silver bullet to solve this. But there plenty ideas for case specific queries even here on SO. Among popular: just round them up, manually calculate increase, switch to victoriametrcs.

Regarding time: time is exact. I guess want to tried to say is that you want "round" time. But Prometheus returns data at end timestamp and then each step before that. So if you want to have you points at say 20:00, 19:00, 18:00 round your timestamp yourself.
